# update two tables at same time in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have the two tables where user is admin its information stores in users table and students information is store in users as well in students table so when students update its table base on id field in students table how to update users table

```
users

id  | email     |password   |firstname    |user_type
1  abc@gmail.com     dfdf       a            0 //(user)
2  xd@gmail.com      dgg         g       1//(student)
3  sa@ggg.com        fjh         dd          1//(student)     

students
id | email      |firstname |lastname| user_id 
2   xd@gmail.com    dgg      g          2 
3   sa@ggg.com      fgh     dd            3
```

and this update query

```
function update($student_id,$data)
    { 

        $this->db->where(array('id' => $student_id));
        return $this->db->update('students',$data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't update multiple tables with one SQL statement. Codeigniter does allow you to use transactions though. Check it out:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Here is the documentation: 
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html

Just a side note: it is best to avoid duplicate content, like the 'firstname' column. Maybe you can find another way to do it without duplicate content.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

---

```
function update($student_id,$data)
{ 
    // update the student table first //
    $this->db->where(array('id' => $student_id));
    return $this->db->update('students',$data);

    //update the user table next//
    $this->db->where(array('id' => $student_id));
    return $this->db->update('users',$data); 

}
```